# how to loop images added to JLable

Tags: java, loops

Can someone help me please.  Here are my codes.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class picturesPanel implements ActionListener
{   

public static JPanel mainPanel;
public static JPanel panel1;
public static JLabel images;
boolean go = false;

private int i = 0;     
private ImageIcon myImage1 = new ImageIcon ("D:\\LCTPShare\\Picture1.gif");
private ImageIcon myImage2 = new ImageIcon ("D:\\LCTPShare\\Picture6.gif");
private ImageIcon myImage3 = new ImageIcon ("D:\\LCTPShare\\Picture3.gif");
private ImageIcon myImage4 = new ImageIcon ("D:\\LCTPShare\\Picture4.gif"); 
private ImageIcon myImage5 = new ImageIcon ("D:\\LCTPShare\\Picture5.gif"); 
private ImageIcon myImage6 = new ImageIcon ("D:\\LCTPShare\\Picture7.gif");
private ImageIcon myImage7 = new ImageIcon ("D:\\LCTPShare\\Picture8.gif");
private ImageIcon[] myImages = new ImageIcon[7];    

public void pictures() 
{    
    myImages[0]=myImage1;
    myImages[1]=myImage2;
    myImages[2]=myImage3;
    myImages[3]=myImage4;
    myImages[4]=myImage5;
    myImages[5]=myImage6;
    myImages[6]=myImage7;

    LineBorder borderA = new LineBorder(Color.RED);
    TitledBorder titledBorderA = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(borderA, "");

    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    mainPanel.setInputVerifier(null);    
    mainPanel.setBorder(titledBorderA);
    FINAL_LCTP_WORKBENCE.buttonsPanel.add(mainPanel, 0);    

    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(260, 115));           
    mainPanel.add(panel1);  

    images = new JLabel();
    images.setIcon(myImage1);     
    panel1.add(images, BorderLayout.CENTER);        
    javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(5000, this);
    timer.start();
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
     i++;           

     if(i == 1)
     {
         images.setIcon(myImages[0]);                                                                                                      

     }
     if(i == 2)
     {
         images.setIcon( myImages[1]);   

     }
     if(i == 3)
     {
         images.setIcon(myImages[2]);   

     }
     if(i == 4)
     {
         images.setIcon(myImages[3]);   

     }   
     if(i == 5)
     {
         images.setIcon(myImages[4]);   

     }          
     if(i == 6)
     {
         images.setIcon(myImages[5]);   

     }
     if(i == 7)
     {
         images.setIcon(myImages[6]);   

     }    


     panel1.revalidate();
     panel1.repaint();

}
```

}

I was able to show my desired images 1 to 6.  How do i make the images shown in my JPanel Loop? My goal is that After image 1 to 6 is shown, it will show again image 1 up to 6, and the process continues until I close my program, or maybe until i click a button that indicate stop.  I'm new at this so please excuse my methods, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code in `actionPerformed()` by

```
images.setIcon(myImages[i]);
i++;
if (i >= myImages.length) {
    i = 0;
}
```